# is main () created with an automatic variable, and if so, what's its purpose?

Tags: c++, stack, activation-record

I was reading through my text book in the *function call stack* section and came across this:

> the activation record tells main how to return to the operating system (i.e., transfer to return address R1) and contains the space for main's automatic variable (i.e., a, which is initialized to 10)

this was news to me, so my questions are:

1. is an automatic variable created?
2. what is its purpose?
3. is its value always the same?

thanks in advance

Comment: I bet the sample main function in the textbook has an automatic variable called "a" which is initialized to 10.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : Here you go: `int main() {int someVariable = 10; return 0;}`

Comment: ya, sorry.  that was a huge over sight, it's because variables, by default are usually initialed as automatic by default.  sorry for your time everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That passage refers to a sample program in your text book. In that sample program, an automatic variable named `a` is declared and initialized to 10.

The sample program might look like this:

```
int main () {
  int a = 10;
  return 42;
}
```

> is an automatic variable created?

Only if you declare one.

> what is its purpose?

The passage describes ordinary automatic variables that you use in your program, for your own purpose.

> is its value always the same?

No.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I just learned about the automatic variables today and that variables are by default automatic.  I didn't put two and two together (that it's just a regular integer) so it threw me off a little.  thanks again

Comment: @LoganBesecker: Variables are automatic by default if they're defined inside a function (between `{` and `}`). They're static (i.e., have static storage duration) by default if they're defined outside any function, at file scope. (But the `static` keyword on a file-scope declaration affects the linkage, not the storage duration.)